# JavaScript: How to like a Facebook wall post (given a Facebook page URL and a Facebook post id) using API Graph?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know how to like a Facebook wall post using API Graph, given a Facebook page URL and a Facebook wall post id. Actually, after having a look at this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/object/likes), I tried to use the JavaScript SDK code that I found there.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var data = { link: 'Facebook_page_link', };
FB.api("/post_id/likes", 'post', data, function(response) {
    if(response === true) {
        alert("done!");
    }
    else{
        alert("Something is wrong!");
    }
});
```

Since that didn't work, I wonder what wrong and missing in my code is. Any idea?

Comment: why like a post with the api? what´s the use case? what access token are you using?

Comment: it seems your code is correct, just make sure you're using page access token

Comment: Have a look at the documentation again, you missed the most important part ... _"Note: as of Nov 17, 2016 we changed the behavior of publishing likes and only support this action with Page Access Tokens."_ You can not like stuff in the name of a user any more, only as a page.

Comment: Not sure what made you think supplying a `link` parameter while trying to like something would make any sense.

Comment: @luschn: Actually, I'm trying to develop a Google Chrome extension that aims to like the recent wall post of a given Facebook page. By the way, could you please explain to me what "page access token " means? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: why would anyone want to like a wall post through a chrome extension, while he could just hit the like directly on facebook.com anyway? i mean, you do have to have it on the screen in order to make it work for the extension, so...i don´t get it.

Comment: @luschn: Actually, that Chrome extension aims to like the recent wall post of each one of given Facebook pages within a given time periods (endlessly). To be honest, between me and you, that's what the company where I had an interview last week (for a job of a web developer) asked me to develop in order to be accepted for the job. Lol :) See what I mean?

Comment: sounds like auto-liking, which is not allowed anyway. tell that to the company instead ;)

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following POST request to like a post.

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/PAGEID_POSTID/likes?access_token=PAGEACCESSTOKEN`

Comment: Could you please explain to me how to get the access_token?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to read through all the documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ and a bit more too to understand how access tokens are generated, what they can/cannot do etc